# Where to move Outlook .NK2 File in Google Apps Profile?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, user-profiles, google-workspace

I have set up a Google Apps profile in Outlook 2007. Having copied my `outlook.NK2` file from  the old profile, I'm not quite sure about the `.NK2` file in the new profile.

Where can I find it? Can I replace the `.NK2` file in my Google Apps profile with the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which OS.

In Windows XP, it is here:

> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\%UserProfile%\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook

In Vista/Windows7, it is here:

> C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook

Yes, you can copy the old one to the new profile, but the name of the file, Outlook.NK2 will match your profile name, which is Outlook by default, so if you created a new profile name, make sure that the NK2 file matches it.